# TLS: failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for <IP> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

Tags: go, https, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

Background:

1. I have a Prometheus process and a Prometheus-PushGateway process in the customer environment
2. I have a go process which use Pusher.Push() function to push some customized metrics to the PushGateway and then PushGateway convey it to the Prometheus.
3. I don't know how the customer deploy the Prometheus-PushGateway, but they gave me a https's address and I can use curl command to visit like:

```
curl -H 'Host: upfs-pgw-nm04-a800.glm.ai' -k https://<IP>:9443/metrics
```

Here it use -k to avoid the permission issue, if cancel it the problem'll appear just like the first problem described below, the condition without -k:

[image]

Part of the code related to the Push fucntion:

```
        // Ignoring contextual environment
    pusher := push.New(pushgatewayAddr, jobName).Collector(reg)

    if err := pusher.Push(); err != nil {
        uflog.ERROR("reportCapacityToPushgateway error: " + err.Error())
        return err
    }
```

The API adress: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/push#Pusher.Push

Problem:

1. Now I encounter a problem during customer testing, see the pic below:

[image]

2. I know the Push-Golang package have a HTTPdoer type and guess it can help to skip the client verify from PushGateway but I don't know how to do it ? In other words, how can I use this golang package to Push without the Permission verification ?
3. I know the Prometheus-PushGateway has a --web.config.file to enable TLS or authentication but I don't know how to config it avoid this problem though I have reviewed this doc from the help info ?
   https://github.com/prometheus/exporter-toolkit/blob/master/docs/web-configuration.md

I haven't tried some ways and I expect that there is a way to solve this permission problem, and I hope that best solution is to be on the go-process rather then the Prometheus-PushGateway as customers have deployed the Prometheus and PushGateway, it's not convenient to ask them to do something more.
I would be extremely grateful if you can help me solve this problem thx !

Comment: Don't ever skip certificate validation in a production environment. Fix the certificate/URL so that they match each other instead. If the URL contains an IP address this address should be given in the certificate too. If the certificate is for an FQDN instead then use this FQDN in your URL.

Comment: It doesn't have a valid certificate, which is why you get the error you screenshotted when you make the request normally. The IP SAN error is a red herring, you only get that because you're calling the IP directly. The only solution is for the customer to deploy a valid certificate, for you to trust their certificate on your server, or to skip certificate verification.

Comment: It cannot be overstated how correct @SteffenUllrich is in this. Skipping certificate validation allows for the easiest MITM attacks imaginable. One malicious proxy or hotspot later and your credentials and data are compromised. And TLS and authentication are not alternatives to each other. They are complementary means to protect your and your customer's privacy.